# ffmpeg sequence of multiple filters syntax

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, alsa, recording

i am trying to use multiple filters in ffpmeg, but it does not allow more than one -af.
so, then i decided to try to do it with a -complex_filter.

```
sudo ffmpeg -f alsa -i default:CARD=Device \
  -filter_complex \
  "lowpass=5000,highpass=200; \
   volume=+5dB; \
   afftdn=nr=0.01:nt=w;" \
  -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -ac 1 -t 00:00:05 -y $recdir/audio_$(date '+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S').mp3
```

it must work, but for some reason i get an error:

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'default:CARD=Device':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1625496748.441207, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xaaab0a8b14e0] No such filter: ''
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

i have tried quotes and others, nothing helps..

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i default:CARD=Device \
  -filter_complex \
  "lowpass=5000,highpass=200,volume=+5dB,afftdn=nr=0.01:nt=w" \
  -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -ac 1 -t 00:00:05 -y $recdir/audio_$(date '+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S').mp3
```

- If you end your filtergraph with `;` then ffmpeg expects another filter. That is why you got the error `No such filter: ''`. Avoid ending with `;`.
- You have a linear series of simple filters so separate the filters with commas. This also means you can still use `-af` instead of `-filter_complex` if you prefer.
- See [FFmpeg Filtering Introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) to see the difference between `;` and `,`.

Comment: when trying -af filters:

Multiple -filter, -af or -vf options specified for stream 0, only the last option '-filter:a volume=+5dB' will be used.

`sudo ffmpeg -f alsa -i default:CARD=Device \
`-af 'lowpass=5000,highpass=200' \
`-af 'afftdn=nr=0.01:nt=w' \
`-af 'volume=+5dB' \
`-c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -ac 1 -t 00:00:05 -y $recdir/audio_$(date '+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S').mp3

`#sorry i can not get how to enter LF in text here ....

Comment: @otomari You can't use multiple `-af`. You can use `-af "lowpass=5000,highpass=200,volume=+5dB,afftdn=nr=0.01:nt=w"`

Comment: thank you very much, removing other -af solved the problem!